# Substring assignment

Tags: javascript, substring

I have an assignment in school but I'm totally stuck.

My assignment: 
Make a program that ask for a text and then write out the text several times. First with just one letter, then with two and so on. For example, if the user write "Thomas", your program should write out "T", "Th, "Tho, "Thom", and so on.

My hopeless attempt
I been trying to use "Substring" and a loop to make it work but I'm not sure I'm on the right path or not. Right now my code look like this:

```
<head> 
<meta charset= "UTF-8"/> 
<title> assignment14 - Johan </title>


<script type="text/javascript"> 



var text= test.length;

for (i=0;i< test.length;i++)    

function printit()
{
var str = test;
var res = str.substring (i, 2);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = res;  
}

    </script>



</head>

<body>
<h1>Assignment 14</h1>
    <form name="f1">
    <input type="text" id="test" value="" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Hämta" onclick="printit(document.getElementById('test'))" />


    </form> 

</body>
```

Just need some kind of hint If I'm going in the right direction or not, should I use some other functions? Very thankful for help.

Comment: use string slice https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite a script.When you want to extract one by one you can use `substring();` function.

**How to Call :** `StringObject.substring (StartPoint,endPoint);`

**Solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function printit(){

var test=document.getElementById("test").value;
var text= test.length;

for (i=0;i<= text;i++)    
{

    var res = test.substring (i, 0);
    document.write(res);
    document.write("<br/>");
}
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `for`-loop for this (whenever possible, I prefer functional style). Instead, I write a function that returns an array of substrings:

```
const substrings = string =>
  Array.from(string).map((_, i) => string.slice(0, i + 1))
```

And here's a [working codepen](https://codepen.io/khai96_/pen/EbMjNj)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. `substring(start,end)` in javascript gives you the consecutive part of the string letters from `start` index to `end`. You just use it in a wrong way for your case. You have to call it like this:

`substring(0,i)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes to your code:
1) use document.getElementById('test').value in printit function call at onclick as you have to send the value of the textbox instead of innerHTML.
2) Modify the printif function-

```
function printit(test)
{
document.getElementById('test').value='';  /*remove existing text from textbox*/
for (i=0;i< test.length;i++)   {
var res = str.substring (0, i+1);
document.getElementById("test").value += ' '+res;  
}
}
```

In printit function empty the text box and then append each substring to the existing text to get "T Th Tho Thom.." and so on
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Output several time using `substring()` method can be done as below, create a `function` which performs this task of extracting the user inputted string on `button` click using `forloop` and `substring()` method.

```js
var intp = document.querySelector("input");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var dv = document.querySelector("div");
btn.onclick = function() {
  var b = intp.value;
  for (var i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
    var c = b.substring(0, i);
    dv.innerHTML += c + "<br/>";
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  width:400px;
  background:#111;
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Click</button>
<br/><br/>
<div></div>
```

You have used a correct way for doing this, but as one of user suggest the `start` and `end` value of `substring()` was not correct.